# How to replace product id?

Tags: php, id

I work with Magento and i want to replace the category ids with ids from another with writing a php code. Can someone help me to do that?

Comment: Are you working on  Magento2?

Comment: Yes i am working with Magento2.

Comment: I added answer below. You can use this code.

Comment: Is it help you, If yes kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2, Below code can help you to create script:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productId = 10001; // YOUR PRODUCT ID

//Delete category from product
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$product = $productRepository->getById($productId);
 
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
$count = count($categoryIds);

if($count > 1){ //if more than one category assigned
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
         try{
            $CategoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($categoryIds[$i],$product->getSku());  //delete category Id from product
         
        }catch(Exception $e){
            //Exception message here        
        }
    }
}
else{
    $CategoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($categoryIds[$i],$product->getSku());  //delete category Id from product
}

//Set new category in product
 $new_category_id_to_set = array('7','10');
 $_categoryLinkRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');
 $_categoryLinkRepository->assignProductToCategories($product->getSku(), $new_category_id_to_set);
?>
```